# Function is not recognizing me passing a vector of node pointers, in C++?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm pretty new to C++, for a binary tree project, I am trying to pass a vector of node pointers into a function that will add/manipulate the tree. The errors are commented below.

Example of one of the function's signatures:

```
void add(vector <Node*> &nodes, int &Aindex, vector <int> A, int value, vector <int> E, int Eindex);
```

Main code:

```
vector <Node*> makeTree(vector <int> A, vector <int> E) {
    vector <Node*> nodes = {};
    int Aindex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < E.size(); i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i % 2 != 0) {
            if (i == 0) {
                create(nodes, Aindex, A, E[i]); // no matching function to call to ERROR.
            } else {
                add(nodes, Aindex, A, E[i], E, i); // no matching function to call to ERROR.
            }
            Aindex++;
        } else {
            if (find(nodes, Aindex, A, E[i]) == false) { // no matching function to call to ERROR.
                create(nodes, Aindex, A, E[i]); // no matching function to call to ERROR.
                Aindex++;
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch everyone keeps asking me to do this... What does it exactly mean? I have read the article. Do you want me to produce a small dummy example? Or give more code for context?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the compiler hasn't seen the respective declarations when it compiles `makeTree`. As you don't show the rest of your code, nobody can verify.

Comment: You are suppose to provide a complete, self-contained program just big enough to exhibit the problem. Note that sometime the vary process of trying to create such an example will lead you to solve the problem. This is a feature.

Comment: A decent compiler these days will, along with the error, barf out a load of extra information and sometimes even have little arrows pointing right at the offending parameter to help you out. Pick one of the errors and add the complete error message to the question. Sometimes the development environments strip out this extra information to show you smaller and less-useful error messages. Find the full build output, it'll be there somewhere, and use it to guide your troubleshooting.

Comment: It is too minimal, it lacks needed declarations. It does not allow to reproduce your problem, because you do not actually describe the problem you encounter. It does not provide an example, because it lacks for example the definition of a data structure that could be used as a parameter. It is not an example of what exactly you have tried, because you do not show how you try to give something as a parameter. On top of that, apart from not describing the problem you have, it simply does not ask a question. (Yes I see the question mark in the title, but that does not make it a question.)

Comment: The fact that you accepted below answer implies that you should have actually asked the question which was answered. And the article does describe that as well. See "Reproducable", "Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it." and similar. So, applying the MRE concept would have solved the problem I had with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that, if those functions aren't in the same file as your "Main code", that they are visible by means some of sort of `include`.

Edit: As pointed out by @QuentinUK, these functions, or their prototypes at least, need to appear before they are called.

Comment: Thank you, but yes they are all in one file.

Comment: They also have to appear first (or their prototypes do).